# How do I get more warnings from javac?

Tags: java, compiler-warnings

I want the Java compiler to give me the highest level of warnings possible. Currently I compile with -Xlint. Is there anyway for me to get more warnings? The warnings provided by Xlint seem paltry.

I just compiled this code with -Xlint and got no warnings:

```
double x = 22/7;
double y = 22/7;

if(x == y) {
  System.err.println("They are equal!");
}
```

If I did this in C++ and compiled using gcc with the option -Wfloat-equal, the compiler would issue a warning. Java issues no warning whatsoever. I am using Java 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no way to get this warning in `javac`. Alternatively, use [FindBug](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) -- it can check this type of pattern.